# How do I get the Gtk Pixbuf icon to show?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, gdkpixbuf

The [hearham.live](https://hearham.com/) RepeaterSTART application no longer has an app icon in the Alt+tab switcher on Ubuntu... or the app switcher on Librem phone. Now I recall this had been working and I am wondering why this piece of code doesn't seem to work anymore?

https://github.com/programmin1/Repeater-START/blob/master/src/repeaterstart.py#L286

```
    if os.path.exists(icon_app_path):
        pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file(icon_app_path)
        self.set_icon(pixbuf)
```

Comment: Did you check if `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/repeaterSTART.svg`  exists?

Comment: Yes it does. I don't know why it doesn't show the icon.